# How to transform all the numbers in a text file

Tags: bash, text, command-line

I have an XML file that contains, among other things, numbers. Something like:

```
<things>
    <a name="cat">
        <vecs>(100,20),(200,40),(50,85)</vecs>
    </a>
    <b name="dog">
        <vecs>(0,10),(5,75)</vecs>
        <ratio>85.5</ratio>
    </b>
    ... many more elements and numbers ...
</things>
```

Unfortunately all of the numbers with `<vecs>` elements in my file are 4 times larger than they should be. I need to multiply them all by 0.25. Numbers in `<ratio>` and other elements are fine. So for example the first `<vecs>` line above *should* read:

```
<vecs>(25,5),(50,10),(12.5,21.25)</vecs>
```

Is there a convenient solution (e.g. UNIX command line tool, bash script, etc.) to processing the file so that I can find all the numbers that live within a particular context (e.g. between `<vecs>` and `</vecs>`), perform a mathematical operation on them, and replace the existing numeric text in each instance with the result of the operation?

And no, I'm not asking you to write a whole program to solve this particular problem in detail. I'm wondering if there is an existing tool for such purposes or a clever combination of existing tools that could accomplish the job.

Comment: Seems like a quick Python script should do the job. Anything, really, that will let you easily read XML from a file, alter specific elements of that XML, and write the changes back.

Comment: @MattBall Yes, I've been thinking this might be the thing that pushes me to learn Python at last. Or Perl or Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The problem itself is fairly easy, but the syntax is uncommon enough to have to use a general purpose script language to tackle the problem. For example in Python you would write something like this

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

def transform(match):
 return '(%.2f,%.2f)' % (int(match.group(1))*0.25,
                         int(match.group(2))*0.25)

for line in file('test.xml'):
    if '<vecs>' in line:
        print(re.sub(r'\((\d+),(\d+)\)',transform,line),end='')
    else:
        print(line,end='')
```

For particular problems your best bet is to learn a script language and use that to solve them.

If you want to use unix tools to do this kind of things sed and awk are your friends.

Comment: thanks for the solution as well as the advice. I've worked in C for years and considered a C-based solution, but this really does look like a case for scripting.